# How to know when an inner property of a MVVM bound property gets modified?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

working on a WPF MVVM project.

I have a TextBlock binding to a model entity property:

```
  <TextBox  Text="{Binding MyEntity.Name}"/>
```

I want a flag to be updated when this MyEntity.Name entity changed.
How can I do that ?

I could obviously set a dedicated property Name:

```
public string Name
{
 get
  {
   return MyEntity.Name;
  }
 set
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

But I m sure you guys will suggest a more elegant ways.

Comment: So the `MyEntity` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: no    ..........................

Comment: Impliment the INotifyPropertyChanged in the MyEntity Class if you haven't the source code so create a wrapper and attach PropertyChangedEvent on

Comment: late answer. I got the idea, thx guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If the entity class does not implement a change interface you probably will have to write wrapper properties and make sure the entity is *only* accessed through those. Maybe there exist code generation tools that could write all the boilerplate for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate and an event. Raise the event when the property `MyEntity.Name` changes.

public string Name
{

```
 get
  {
   return MyEntity.Name;
  }
 set
  {
      // Raise the event here
  }
}
```

Handle the event and set a flag in the view.